# fixed left menu with right scrollable div not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a fixed left menu exactly like the one seen on [bento.io](https://www.bento.io/tracks/web-fundamentals) so that I can use angular to create a scroll spy and navigation but for some reason It is not working at all. My left fixed menu disappears from the window when i start adding fixed to it leaving the right part occupying the entire screen

Here is a link to what I have done so far [on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kejehabena/1/edit)

UPDATE: I am looking for a CSS only solution because I am using angularjs

Comment: Can you throw some codes here?

Comment: @Bazinga777 if you wish edit your code. make it as editable JS bin. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var sc = $(window).scrollTop()
if (sc > 500) {
    $(".course-menu").addClass("fixed-menu")
} else {
    $(".course-menu").removeClass("fixed-menu")
}
});
```

**CSS**

```
.fixed-menu
{
   position: fixed;
   top:80px;
}
```

dependencies `JQuery`

Answer (score 0):

use

**CSS**:

```
leftmenu-class{

position:fixed;
top:100px //your preferred height from top;
}
```

[**just a simple demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljco0ro6/)  //just to tell the working

here is the [**updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljco0ro6/1/)

Again [**Re-updated**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljco0ro6/3/) after suggestion from @Gold Pearl

add **js**

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        //After scrolling 100px from the top...
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 500) {

            $('.left').css('position', 'fixed');
            $('.left').css('top', '0px');


            //Otherwise remove inline styles and thereby revert to original stying
        } else {
            $('.left').css('position', 'absolute');
            $('.left').css('top', '500px');

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: But this not like that, he wants.

Comment: @GoldPearl : what then he needs

Comment: He need fixed menu after 500px scrolled. like this https://www.bento.io/tracks/web-fundamentals

Comment: Sorry too. i didn't seen your css edits. have you look out your fiddle. after the reach >500 it works well, again we scrolled to top the div til there in top because of your top value not be changed in else condition. I have updated your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Ljco0ro6/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67094/discussion-between-gold-pearl-and-sajad-karuthedath).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo of something very similar that I just whipped up. Hopefully it helps you out.
[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ojm39Ljz/8/embedded/result/)

You can click the "Edit" button in the top right to look at my full HTML, CSS, and JS. http://jsfiddle.net/ojm39Ljz/8/

**CSS**

Initially the menu bar thingy is static with the page, but later we will want it to be fixed so we create another class with its fixed position.

```
.floating-bar {
    position: static;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.is-floating {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

**Javascript (jQuery)**

Then we use jQuery to check if the user has scrolled or not. Once the user has scrolled past the offset that we set (height of the header) , the function adds the class is-floating that we created earlier to the menu bar thingy. If the user scrolls back up above the offset, the function removes the is-floating class from the menu bar thingy.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Set offset to the height of header in px
    var offset = 500; 

    //On scroll, it calls the function floatingMenu()
    floatingMenu();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        //alert("checking menu");
        floatingMenu();
    });

    //If distance from top of window is greater than the offset, it adds the class is-floating to the floating-bar
    //If distance is less than the offset, it removes the is-floating class
    function floatingMenu() {
        if (($(window).scrollTop() > offset) && !($("#floating-bar").hasClass('is-floating'))) {
            //alert("adding class");
            $("#floating-bar").addClass('is-floating');
        } else if (($(window).scrollTop() < offset) && ($("#floating-bar").hasClass('is-floating'))) {
            //alert("removing class");
            $("#floating-bar").removeClass("is-floating");
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helped, good luck with your project!